# What the interpretation of `ps --forest` when executing bash command groups?

Tags: bash, background-process, jobs, subshell

According to the bash manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping):

> ( list )
> Placing a list of commands between parentheses causes a subshell environment to be created
>
> { list; }
> Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context.

Now, I'm confused by how they looks in `ps --forest`.

If I run `( sleep 10 )` or `{ sleep 10; }`, both appear as:

```
myuser   710405  0.0  0.0  14552  7484 pts/2    S    16:18   0:00  |   \_ bash
myuser   723783  0.0  0.0   8424   428 pts/2    S+   16:26   0:00  |       \_ sleep 10
```

it seems that no subprocess is created in both cases. Now, when I run the command groups in background, the behavior differs. `(sleep 10) &` still looks:

```
myuser   710405  0.0  0.0  14552  7484 pts/2    S+   16:18   0:00  |   \_ bash
myuser   725828  0.0  0.0   8424   480 pts/2    S    16:27   0:00  |       \_ sleep 10
```

but `{ sleep 10; } &` now looks:

```
myuser   710405  0.0  0.0  14552  7484 pts/2    S+   16:18   0:00  |   \_ bash
myuser   728247  0.0  0.0  14036  5140 pts/2    S    16:29   0:00  |       \_ bash
myuser   728248  0.0  0.0   8424   460 pts/2    S    16:29   0:00  |           \_ sleep 10
```

Based on the first (non-backgrounded) observation, it seems that subshells are not spawned as (new) processes. But then, why would `{} &` generates one, in particular, considering that it's not supposed to spawn a subshell (while `() &` should)?